# ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY not set but still have Error 1140

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-mode, mysql-error-1140

I am finalizing the implementation of my website but now I have a problem that occurs online that I have not locally.

I get this error:

```
failed: Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN (), MAX (), COUNT (), ...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

result of a SQL query

I searched in lot of forums on the net, most users advise to change the query that I can not / do not want, or they say it was probably in the sql-mode: enabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` of the server

My sql-mode is empty on my server online (I can see with the query `select @@sql_mode;`)
More to be sure, I put `sql_mode='' in my.cnf`.

But the problem remains.

Is this due to my version of mysql 5.0.44 on my server online and locally 5.1.32 (which I do not have this bug ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are right. This happens because of **MySQL version.**
Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297661/1031945)

How to check MySQL version?

```
mysql> SELECT version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.28    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For testing sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, I created table `patient` with two columns `id, name` and inserted records. Remember sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not default set, you need to set if you want.

1)MySQL version **5.0.45-community-nt**

```
SELECT name, MAX(id) FROM patient;
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

It failed, there was no point in setting the sql_mode to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` as it won't allow nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

2)MySQL version **5.1.40-community**

```
mysql> SELECT name, MAX(id) from patient;
+----------+--------+
| MAX(id)  | name   |
+----------+--------+
|       33 | aniket |
+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Then after setting sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

```
mysql> set sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name, MAX(id) from patient;
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

3)MySQL version **5.5.28**

```
mysql> SELECT name, MAX(id) from patient;
+----------+--------+
| MAX(id)  | name   |
+----------+--------+
|       33 | aniket |
+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Then after setting sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

```
mysql> set sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name, MAX(id) from patient;
ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

**Conclusion**

As you can see query failed on version 5.0.45, and succeed on/after 5.1.40, 5.5.28 and 5.1.32 (as you mentioned in question).
Before MySQL version [5.1.10(not sure)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) query without `GROUP BY` fails irrespective of sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set or not.

Some interesting bugs and sql_mode faq link

1. [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode is overly restrictive](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8510)
2. [sql-mode: only full group by mode not working](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27874)
3. [MySQL 5.0 FAQ: Server SQL Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html)